# filtrar registros delphi

Tags: ms-access, delphi

estoy trabajando en un proyecto en delphi xe6 y componentes ADO y MS ACCESS como base de tados.

cuando escribo una letra en el edit1 por ejemplo la letra 'a' me aparece este error "argumentos incorrectos, fuera del intervalo permitido o en conflicto con otros". El código relevante es este:

```
DataSource1.DataSet.Close;
DataSource1.DataSet.Filter:= 'nombre like' + quotedstr(Edit1.Text + '%');
DataSource1.DataSet.Open;
DataSource1.DataSet.Filtered := True;
```

Comment: bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. ¿Cómo estás obteniendo actualmente los registros? ¿Para qué efecto los quieres filtrar?. Te recomiendo darte una vuelta por [El recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para ubicarte sobre el funcionamiento de StackOverflow.

Comment: veo que no has añadido más información a tu pregunta, me veo en la penosa necesidad de sugerir que se cierre, pues en su estado actual no puede responderse. Sigue abierta la invitación a que la edites, para añadir información y de esta manera pueda responderse (sin ser cerrada o incluso re-abrirla luego de que lo esté). Un saludo.

Comment: el error deja de ocurrir si quitas la línea que activa el filtro? o en qué línea ocurre exactamente?

Comment: quite la linea que activa el filtro, cuando quiero realizar una búsqueda no muestra ningún resultado

Comment: sigue siendo poco clara la pregunta.

Comment: EL filtro lo estas metiendo en algun metodo de algun boton? o esta en onchange de el edit?
Cabe mencionar que si te funciona a la primera y despues no, cuando hagas el close te recomiendo que el filtered lo pongas como falso
Por otro lado el filtered:=true ponlo antes del open.

Comment: También podrías cambiar la consulta dinamicamente para que en el SQL uses el LIKE

Answer (score 1):

veo dos posibles problemas
- despues de Like deja un espacio en blanco que lo separe de las comillas
   'nombre like ' + quotedstr(Edit1.Text + '%');

- el quoteStr incluye comillas dobles y es posible que necesite comilla simple, asi que puedes sustituir Quotestr por una comilla simple, que recuerda que si va junto a otra comilla se ponen dos comillas simples '', que no es lo mismo que una doble  "

Answer (score 0):

En realidad el problema es que no puedes usar el comando LIKE en los filtros, los operadores disponibles para el filtro son los siguientes:
<, >, >=, <=, =, <>, AND, NOT, OR, +, -, *, /
[Puedes verificarlos aquí](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/5datasetsettingthefilterproperty_xml.html)

Sin embargo para obtener el resultado que esperas puedes modificar la cláusula WHERE de la consulta agregando efectivamente el comando tal como lo estas haciendo:

> 'nombre like' + quotedstr(Edit1.Text + '%');